# Как сделать все новые элементы в GridPane "HPos.CENTER"?

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Можно ли указать для всех элементов, которые будут добавляться в GridPane, чтобы они сразу были HPos.CENTER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить для существующих элементов, чтобы у них был HPos.CENTER :

```
gridPane.getChildren().forEach(n -> GridPane.setHalignment(n, HPos.CENTER));
```

И так же повесить лисенер на добавление элементов, чтобы им так же проставлялось это свойство :

```
gridPane.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener < Node > () {@
    Override
    public void onChanged(Change <? extends Node > c) {
        if (c.next()) {
            GridPane.setHalignment(c.getAddedSubList().get(0), HPos.CENTER);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решён)

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать правило для всех столбцов\строк:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
for ( int i = 0; i != COLUMN_COUNT; i++ ) {
    grid.getColumnConstraints().add( new ColumnConstraints( -1, -1, -1, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true ) );
//  grid.getRowConstraints().add( new RowConstraints( -1, -1, -1, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true ) );
}
```